# play banner video forward and backward using scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I'm developing a video banner that should go forward and backward using page scroll.
I have already developed using some references but this is not working with a banner.On-scroll video does not go forward or backward with scroll activity.
I added my code. I want smooth scrolling. I don't think there is a problem with javascript.

```js
const registerVideo = (bound, video) => {
    bound = document.querySelector(bound);
    video = document.querySelector(video);
    const scrollVideo = ()=>{
        if(video.duration) {
            const distanceFromTop = window.scrollY + bound.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            const rawPercentScrolled = (window.scrollY - distanceFromTop) / (bound.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight);
            const percentScrolled = Math.min(Math.max(rawPercentScrolled, 0), 1);
            
            video.currentTime = video.duration * percentScrolled;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(scrollVideo);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(scrollVideo);
}


registerVideo("#bound-one", "#bound-one video");
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
  
  #bound-one {
    background: #d0d8db;
  }
  
 
  .scroll-bound {
    height: 500vh;
  }
  
  .content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .scroll-bound video {
    width: 80%;
  }
  

#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="app">
        <div id="bound-one" class="scroll-bound">
            <video id='myVideo' width="600" muted preload>
               <source src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tvibhu12/video/upload/v1594987784/mambo_drfrs1.mp4" type="video/webm">
               
     </video>
          
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi pro.</p>
            
          </div>
        
      
        
    </div>
```

Comment: In effect, you are cancelling out `window.scrollY` in your calculations. You add it to `distanceFromTop` but then end up subtracting it your `rawPercentScrolled` calculation. Ergo 5 - 5 = 0. This leaves you with only `bound.getBoundingClientRect().top` as your dividend.

Comment: sorry, I'm new in programming but the same logic works with this video. how is it possible - [link](https://objective-panini-9183bc.netlify.app/)